# Allowing inserts in worksheet_change event

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a worksheet change event where if the column I is altered (Date added), it will insert it to a new sheet and delete it.

However, whenever I insert a row, it will automatically take that row and insert it to the other sheet, then delete it. How can I prevent it, so that it will only do an worksheet change event as long as the cell has a value so that I can insert?

I was think that I could nest the IF statement a bit further by checking `ActiveCell.Value <> ""`, however that changes when the cell is clicked off.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim LastRowCompleted As Long
    Dim RowToDelete As Long

    RowToDelete = 0
    LastRowCompleted = Sheets("completed").Cells(Sheets("completed").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowCompleted = LastRowCompleted + 1 'Next row after last row
    Set KeyCells = Range("I:I")


    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Cut and Paste Row
        Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("completed").Range(LastRowCompleted & ":" & LastRowCompleted)
        'Mark to delete row
        RowToDelete = Target.EntireRow.Row

    Call DeleteRow(RowToDelete)
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If



End Sub

Sub DeleteRow(Row As Long)
    If Row > 0 Then
        Rows(Row).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Application.Intersect(Range("I:I"), Target)

    If Not KeyCells Is Nothing Then
        If KeyCells.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub '<<<<<<<
        If KeyCells.Value <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Target.EntireRow
                .Copy Sheets("completed").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Delete
            End With
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Note it's possible for a user to change multiple rows at once, but your code does not handle that: if you try to compare a multi-cell range's Value to a single value that will raise a runtime error (because you're trying to compare an array to a single value)